# JQuery: toggle newly created DIV -> links to $(this) instead of $(this).closest()

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a link called "Reply" in a comment section. When clicking the link, a comment box will pop up. If I reclick the "reply" button, I want this (and all other commentboxes) to disappear. Currently it doesn't disappear and keeps opening more comment boxes.

```
$('.replylink').click(function(event){ // Create comment box after clicking reply
event.stopPropagation();
var commentBox = $('<div class="comment-box"></div>');
$(this).closest('div').after(commentBox);
});
```

I tried several things with toggle() but if I do

```
$($(this).closest('div').after(commentBox)).toggle();
```

for example, it will toggle the "reply" link. So the reply link disappears and the comment box appears. I don't understand how to toggle only the comment box. Anyone out there that can help a noob out? thnx!

Comment: Do you want to remove the comment box? or just hide it?

Comment: @OliverTrampleasure I guess removing, just like I created the div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will open a `.comment-box` if it doesn't exist, and delete it if it does exist for individual threads.

I've added a class to your `.closest()` function, if you just look for a `div` then that is pretty broad! If you add a class you will find it much better - for instance then you can add multiple divs and wrappers between your reply link and the wrapper. You may not need to do it now... but you might in the future! This means your code is more future-proof.

I've commented the code below. It will work for multiple threads / comment sections on a single page, but will also work just fine for a single comment area.

I also appended the comment box to `.before()` the reply link rather than `.after()`... It felt more natural from a UI perspective but is obviously a purely stylistic change.

---

## Demo

```js
// Create comment box after clicking reply
$('.replylink').click(function(event) {

  // Stop default action for click (i.e. going to top of page)
  event.preventDefault();

  // Set wrapping thread div
  // this lets you have multiple threads on the same page (if needed)
  thread = $(this).closest("div.thread");

  // Check if thread has an opened comment box
  if (thread.find(".comment-box").length > 0) {

    // Delete any comment-box within this comment thread
    thread.find(".comment-box").remove();


  } else {

    // Uncomment the line below if you want to close all other comment boxes
    // $(".comment-box").remove();

    // Create a coment box if it doesn't exist
    var commentBox = $('<div class="comment-box"></div>');
    $(this).before(commentBox);

  }

});
```

```css
.comment-box {
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.thread {
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="thread">
  <h3>Thread One</h3>
  <a href="#" class="replylink">Reply</a>
</div>

<div class="thread">
  <h3>Thread Two</h3>
  <a href="#" class="replylink">Reply</a>
</div>

<div class="thread">
  <h3>Thread Three</h3>
  <a href="#" class="replylink">Reply</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot for your quick and correct input, it's much appreciated.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped

Comment: One more question. In your code snippet example, is it possible to have only one comment box open, so if I open one on "thread one" and I click the reply link on "thread 3", it will open there and close the one on "thread one"?

Comment: `$(".comment-box").remove();` will remove all comment boxes, just put that in before you create your new one. I've added a commented line in my code to show where it should go.

Comment: It's that easy huh. Thank you kindly, have a nice day :)